# In NestJS, how do you only return a select group of a OneToMany relation when searching for an entity by its ID?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, one-to-many, relation

I'm using NestJS 10 and TypeORM 0.3.17.  I have this entity ...

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Contact, (contact) => contact.owner, {
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  contacts?: Contact[];
    ...
}
```

in which the Contact entity has a field "isPrimary" ...

```
@Entity()
export class Contact {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

    ...
  @Column({ default: false })
  isPrimary: boolean;
```

I want to write a method that will return the user entity by its ID as well as its related contacts but only if the Contact objects, but only those related contact objects with "isPrimary" being equal to true.  So far I have this

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository,
    ...
  ) {}

    ...
  async findById(id: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.userRepository.findOne({
      select: ['email', 'id', 'refreshToken', 'isEmailConfirmed'],
      relations: ['contacts', 'contacts.mailingAddress', 'contacts.mailingAddress.region'],
      where: { id: id },
    });
  }
```

but this currently returns all the contact objects associated with the user and I only want the ones returned with "isPrimary" being true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `findById` method to filter the contacts based on the `isPrimary` property. That can be done using a [query builder provided by TypeORM](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder#what-is-querybuilder).
See also  "[Using TypeORM’s QueryBuilder in NestJS](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-typeorms-querybuilder-nestjs/)" from [Eze Sunday](https://blog.logrocket.com/author/ezesunday/) as an example/tutorial.

In your case, using database-level filtering during query execution:

```js
async findById(id: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
  return this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder("user")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.contacts", "contact")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("contact.mailingAddress", "mailingAddress")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("mailingAddress.region", "region")
    .where("user.id = :id", { id })
    .andWhere("contact.isPrimary = true")
    .select(["user.email", "user.id", "user.refreshToken", "user.isEmailConfirmed", 
             "contact", "mailingAddress", "region"])
    .getOne();
}
```

That uses a query builder to join the `contacts` relation and applies a condition to select only those contacts where `isPrimary` is true.

When using [`leftJoinAndSelect` in TypeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/d184d8598c057ce8fa54815e669b567238f3a86e/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts#L580-L609), you need to specify each relation you want to join and select explicitly: `leftJoinAndSelect` is used for each related entity (`contacts`, `mailingAddress`, and `region`) to make sure they are included in the result.
The `where` clause specifies the user ID, and `andWhere` is used to filter contacts where `isPrimary` is true.
The `select` method is used to specify the fields to be included in the final result for each entity.

---

A simpler method would involve in-memory filtering after data retrieval:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}

  async findById(id: string): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
      select: ['email', 'id', 'refreshToken', 'isEmailConfirmed'],
      relations: ['contacts', 'contacts.mailingAddress', 'contacts.mailingAddress.region'],
      where: { id },
    });

    if (user && user.contacts) {
      user.contacts = user.contacts.filter(contact => contact.isPrimary);
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

But if a user has a large number of contacts, it involves fetching all contacts and then filtering: less efficient.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Regarding the firstsolution you have, I'm noticing the related fields to contcat (e.g. contact.mailingAddress) are not getting returned, despite them being listed in the "relations" section.  Is this related to the addition of the "leftJoinAndSelect" clause?

Comment: @Dave True. I have updated the answer to address that.